# Creating Spring MVC app

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven, spring-mvc

I am using Eclipse Kepler, and i have installed Spring IDE and STS but when i created Spring MVC Template project i have got errors, then i went to Maven Update options but i have got error. I don't know why. Please, help!

Errors:
Error during build of project [firstSpring]
Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'Faceted Project Validation Builder' on project 'firstSpring'.
Could not initialize class org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.project.facet.IJ2EEFacetConstants
Errors running builder 'Validation' on project 'firstSpring'.
org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.project.facet.IJ2EEFacetConstants

An internal error occurred during: "J2EE Component Mapping Update".
org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.project.facet.IJ2EEFacetConstants

Comment: You don't need Spring IDE and STS. STS is enough: just install it and you should be good to go.

Comment: i have installed it, but i got that error i have posted when trying to compile spring project

Comment: Are you behind a proxy? i had similar issues but configuring proxy in the maven settings.xml worked for me

Comment: The issue seems to persist, seems like something to do with jdt facets

Answer (score 10):

Found a solution atlast, the issue is caused by STS removing some of the facet dependancies, doing the below solved the issue for me in **Eclipse Kepler SR2**

Go to **Install New Software** work with update site *"Kepler - http://download.eclipse.org/releases/kepler"*
under   **Web, XML, Java EE and OSGi Enterprise Development**" select the below items and proceed to update

> Eclipse Faceted Project Framework
>
> Eclipse Faceted Project Framework JDT Enablement
>
> Eclipse Java EE Developer Tools

Comment: In  my case, I was using Eclipse Mars Release, and had to install this component.  

[This was an update,  as I already had the m2e functionality available in Eclipse and was successfully running Maven goals inside Eclipse.   

```m2e - Maven Integration for Eclipse (includes Incubating components) 1.6.2.20150902-0002

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the WTP J2EE thing would have been enough, but I didn't take that route

You could have installed the WTP features into your Eclipse for Java 
Developers installation. In general you can always add features to an 
existing installation as opposed to re-installing or keeping multiple 
installations around.